# Uncaught Exception in heightForHeaderInSection

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I receive the following error, trying to design a preferences tableview.

```
    2015-02-19 21:19:49.204 MyApp[8337:285561] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000110859b95 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001123aebb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001107501fe -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:] + 190
    3   UIKit                               0x000000011161df2a -[UITableViewDataSource tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:] + 39
    4   UIKit                               0x00000001111f0e58 -[UITableView _delegateWantsHeaderForSection:] + 261
    5   UIKit                               0x000000011137b183 -[UISectionRowData refreshWithSection:tableView:tableViewRowData:] + 162
    6   UIKit                               0x0000000111381645 -[UITableViewRowData rectForFooterInSection:heightCanBeGuessed:] + 320
    7   UIKit                               0x000000011138173a -[UITableViewRowData heightForTable] + 56
    8   UIKit                               0x00000001111cd870 -[UITableView _updateContentSize] + 381
    9   UIKit                               0x00000001111ec5a3 -[UITableView setContentInset:] + 336
    10  UIKit                               0x000000011121e6ef -[UIViewController _setNavigationControllerContentInsetAdjustment:] + 501
    11  UIKit                               0x000000011eb19b89 -[UIViewControllerAccessibility _setNavigationControllerContentInsetAdjustment:] + 80
    12  UIKit                               0x00000001112541a6 -[UINavigationController _computeAndApplyScrollContentInsetDeltaForViewController:] + 432
    13  UIKit                               0x0000000111254323 -[UINavigationController _layoutViewController:] + 116
    14  UIKit                               0x0000000111254825 -[UINavigationController _updateScrollViewFromViewController:toViewController:] + 216
    15  UIKit                               0x0000000111249957 -[UINavigationController _startCustomTransition:] + 1657
    16  UIKit                               0x000000011125567f -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 386
    17  UIKit                               0x00000001112561ce -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 43
    18  UIKit                               0x000000011139eded -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 202
    19  UIKit                               0x000000011eb3351e -[UILayoutContainerViewAccessibility layoutSubviews] + 43
    20  UIKit                               0x0000000111176040 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 521
    21  QuartzCore                          0x0000000114c2c38a -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 146
    22  QuartzCore                          0x0000000114c20c46 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 380
    23  QuartzCore                          0x0000000114c20ab6 _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 24
    24  QuartzCore                          0x0000000114b8cf1a _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 242
    25  QuartzCore                          0x0000000114b8e0a5 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 447
    26  QuartzCore                          0x0000000114b8e73f _ZN2CA11Transaction17observer_callbackEP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 89
    27  CoreFoundation                      0x000000011078cd27 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
    28  CoreFoundation                      0x000000011078cc80 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 368
    29  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000110782ab3 __CFRunLoopRun + 1123
    30  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001107823e6 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
    31  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000114512a3e GSEventRunModal + 161
    32  UIKit                               0x00000001110f5b60 UIApplicationMain + 1282
    33  MyApp                 0x000000010fe687f7 main + 135
    34  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000112b52145 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

I suggest, that something in tableView:heightForHeaderInSection gets messed up, but I cannot guess what happens in there.

Here are the other relevant classes:
PreferencesTableViewController

```
import UIKit

class PreferencesTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    let factory = PreferencesCellFactory()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        factory.setTitleForSection(0, title: "Off")
        factory.createSwitcherCell("Fallback-Modus", subtitle: "No-Subtitle")
        factory.createEditorCell("Shortname", subtitle: "Shortname") 


        factory.setTitleForSection(1, title: "New")
        //factory.createEditorCell("New Testcell", subtitle: "Hallo", section: 1)

        // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
        // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

        // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
        // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
        // Return the number of sections.
        return factory.numberOfSections()

    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete method implementation.
        // Return the number of rows in the section.
        return factory.numberOfRowsInSection(section)
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell { 
        return factory.getCellForSectionWithIndex(SectionNr: indexPath.section, index: indexPath.row) // returns correct cell
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return factory.getTitleForSection(SectioNr: section) // returns correct header
    }


}
```

PreferencesCellFactory

```
import Foundation

class PreferencesCellFactory {
    var sections : [[UITableViewPreferencesCell]]
    var sectionTitles : [String]

    init() {
        sections        = [[UITableViewPreferencesCell]]()
        sectionTitles   = [String]()
    }

    func numberOfSections() -> Int {
        return sections.count
    }


    func numberOfRowsInSection(section: Int) -> Int{
        return sections[section].count
    }


    func setTitleForSection(index: Int, title: String!){
        if sectionTitles.count == index {
            sectionTitles.append(title)
        }
        else {
         sectionTitles[index] = title
        }
    }



    func createEditorCell(title: String, subtitle: String){
        createEditorCell(title, subtitle: subtitle, section: 0)
    }


    func createEditorCell(title: String, subtitle: String, section: Int){


        if sections.count == section {
            sections.append([UITableViewPreferencesCell]())
        }

        let cell = UITableViewEditorCell()
        cell.textLabel?.text         = title
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text   = subtitle
        sections[section].append(cell)
        println("Test")
    }


    func createSwitcherCell(title: String, subtitle: String){
        createSwitcherCell(title, subtitle: subtitle, section: 0)
    }


    func createSwitcherCell(title: String, subtitle: String, section: Int){
        // Wenn noch keine Sections angelegt sind, muss erst eine initialisiert werden
        if sections.count == 0 {
            sections.append([UITableViewPreferencesCell]())
        }

        let cell = UITableViewSwitcherCell()
        cell.textLabel?.text         = title
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text   = subtitle
        sections[section].append(cell)
    }



    func getCellAtIndex(index: Int) -> UITableViewPreferencesCell{
        if sections.count == 0 {
            NSLog("Sections Array ist leer")
        }
        return getCellForSectionWithIndex(SectionNr: 0, index: index)
    }



    func getCellForSectionWithIndex(SectionNr section: Int, index: Int) -> UITableViewPreferencesCell{
        if sections.count == 0 {
            NSLog("Sections Array ist leer")
        }
        return sections[section][index]
    }




    func getCells() -> [UITableViewPreferencesCell]{
        if sections.count == 0 {
            NSLog("Sections Array ist leer")
        }
        return getCellsForSection(SectionNr: 0)
    }



    func getCellsForSection(SectionNr section: Int) -> [UITableViewPreferencesCell]{
        if sections.count == 0 {
            NSLog("Sections Array ist leer")
        }
        return sections[section]
    }



    func getTitleForSection(SectioNr section: Int) -> String {
        if sectionTitles.count == 0 {
           NSLog("SectionTitles Array ist leer")
            return "Not titles found"
        }
        return sectionTitles[section]
    }
}
```

I hope anyone can help. I can give more details if necessary.

Thanks in advance

P.S.: If numberOfSectionsInTableView returns 1. the error does not occur

#

1st step to solution:

I added all these methods and now it seems to work as intended, but WHY do I have to implement them?

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 50.0
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 50.0
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 50.0
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 50.0
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 50.0
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, indentationLevelForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Int {
        return 0
    }
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        return UIView()
    }
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        return UIView()
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was using static cells for the tableview. That means, all the mentioned methods have to be implemented. Switching back to dynamic cells fixed the issue without problems.

If you use static cells, you really have to implement all the viewing properties like the headerView etc.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem in this part:

```
func getTitleForSection(SectioNr section: Int) -> String {
        if sectionTitles.count == 0 {
           NSLog("SectionTitles Array ist leer")
            return "Not titles found"
        }
        return sectionTitles[section]
    }
```

as you could see in error log, it's appear in `[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]` 
So if you `sectionTitles`array has, lets say, one element and you ask 1-st, 2-nd or bigger index, then your app will throw exception (and crush). You should check number of objects in this array before doing `sectionTitles[section]`

---

UPD:

I have question about your code:

Your `sections` in `PreferencesCellFactory` has type `UITableViewPreferencesCell` (of course it custom class), but you doing `sections[section].append(cell)` subscript for it. Douse you implement it and how it looks like?

Because without it I can't reproduce code, and if I comments it, then app doesn't crush.

Comment: but I do have as many titles asI do have sections. why is that a problem then?

Comment: Are you 100 percent sure? It's better to put something like println() method inside getTitleForSection method

Comment: Print section and sectionTitles.count please. Could you send here debug results befor crush?

Comment: thanks again for the help. I added the println. the method getTitleForSection does not get called before the crash.

Comment: I set a breakpoint in numberOfSectionsInTableView to print the factory values: Thats what I get:

 ![Debug output](http://i.imgur.com/N2gtiCn.png).

Comment: Maybe you could try to implement "func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat" method in your code? I heard that there some problems with dynamic hight in iOS 8, but I'm not sure.

Comment: It does not help. I added: heightForHeaderInSection and estimatedHeightForHeaderInSection. I cannot find out whats wrong. Please help me =)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71343/discussion-between-alex-zimin-and-gutenmorgenuhu).